# How to redraw a saved image created using bezier path

Tags: iphone

I have a problem. I am building an app in which we can draw using bezier path. But I don't know how we save this drawing and redraw it again using bezier path with the same properties as at the design time.

Sorry for my poor English.

Thanks,

Vipendra

Answer (score 0):

[There i found how to save CGPath](http://www.mlsite.net/blog/?p=1312)

Modify code to save other properties of UIBezierPath. And use that.